# Is it possible to build an Angular 8 web app with latest CSS & HTML5 features that supported fully by chrome 49?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, polyfills

I am developing a ERP desktop app using Angular 8

I also use latest 2019 HTML5 and CSS3 features

I want to develop a cross platform  desktop app that supports Windows XP

I decided to use NW.js which also supports Win XP

But the problem is

> Only the version 0.14.7 of NW.js supports Win XP. So NW.js bundled
>   with chrome 49 since Chrome 49 is the last version for XP by Google

**My Issue**

Since only Chrome 49 for XP , I need to support that version fully

Now the issue is , Chrome 49 don't support latest CSS3 features , such as Grid and Flex

Also latest HTML5 tags are also not supported

**My Need**

Now I  need `a technology that Poly Fill` all of these `3 components` , so it will be converted to Chrome 49 version

- HTML5 2019
- CSS3 2019
- JS & TS (ES2019)

For instance , If I use CSS3 Grid Layout , that technology have to  polyfill by adding additional CSS styles to to make it compatible with chrome 49 and create a Grid

In the same way , HTML5 `input type="datetime"` converted to additional JS elements to show a Date time picker

I heared that Angular 8 supports differential loading to produce ES5 version of the App to support old browsers

But does it also convert CSS and HTML script to be compatible with old browsers

Also , Does Babal convert CSS3 also ?

Please guide me

Comment: Yes you can. With older version of google chrome you need to use some browser prefixes. And you can see through caniuse.com

Comment: Yeah . I need an automated framework that convert automatically , for example , it have to add that browser prefix automatically @batgerel.e